# What's a good way in Akka to wait for a group of Actors to respond?

Tags: scala, akka, future

In Akka, I want to send out a "status" message to actors in a cluster for their status.  These actors may be various states of health, including dead/unable to respond.

I want to wait up to some time, say 10 seconds, then proceed with whatever results I happened to receive back in that time limit.  I don't want to fail the whole thing because 1 or 2 were having issues and didn't responded/timed-out at 10 seconds.

I've tried this:

```
object GetStats {
  def unapply(n: ActorRef )(implicit system: ActorSystem): Option[Future[Any]] = Try {
    implicit val t: Timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
    n ? "A" 
  }.toOption
}
...
val z = List(a,b,c,d)  // where a-d are ActorRefs to nodes I want to status
val q = z.collect {
   case GetStats(s) => s
}
// OK, so here 'q' is a List[Future[Any]]
val allInverted = Future.sequence(q) // now we have Future[List[Any]]
val ok =  Await.result(allInverted, 10 seconds).asInstanceOf[List[String]]
println(ok)
```

The problem with this code is that it seems to throw a TimeoutException if 1 or more don't respond.  Then I can't get to the responses that did come back.

Comment: Why can't you ask their supervisors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, you really need to collect at least partial statistics every 10 seconds - the solution is to convert "not responding" to actual failure.

To achieve this, just increase the `Await` timeout a bit in comparision with `implicit val t:Timeout` for ask. After that your futures itselves (returned from `?`) will fail earlier. So you can [recover](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) them:

```
// Works only when AskTimeout >> AwaitTimeout
val qfiltered = q.map(_.map(Some(_)).recover{case _ => None}) //it's better to match TimeoutException here instead of `_`
val allInverted = Future.sequence(q).map(_.flatten)
```

Example:

```
scala> class MyActor extends Actor{ def receive = {case 1 => sender ! 2; case _ =>}}
defined class MyActor

scala> val a = sys.actorOf(Props[MyActor])
a: akka.actor.ActorRef = Actor[akka://1/user/$c#1361310022]

scala> implicit val t: Timeout = Timeout(1 seconds)
t: akka.util.Timeout = Timeout(1 second)

scala> val l = List(a ? 1, a ? 100500).map(_.map(Some(_)).recover{case _ => None})
l: List[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Any]]] = List(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7faaa183, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1b51e0f0)

scala> Await.result(Future.sequence(l).map(_.flatten), 3 seconds)
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res29: List[Any] = List(2)
```

If you want to know which Future didn't respond - remove `flatten`.

Receiving partial response should be enough for continously collecting statistics, as if some worker actor didn't respond in time - it will respond next time with actual data and without any data lost. But you should correcly process worker's lifecycle and not loose (if it matters) any data inside actor itself.

If the reason of timeouts is just high pressure on system - you may consider:

- separate pool for workers
- backpressure
- caching for input requests (when system overloaded).

If the reason of such timeouts is some remote storage - then partial response is correct way to process it if client is ready for that. WebUI for example may warn a user that shown data may not be full using some spinning thing. But don't forget to not block actors with storage requests (futures may help) or at least move them to the separrate thread-pool.

If worker actor didn't respond because of failure (like exception) - you can still send notification to sender from your `preRestart` - so you can also receive the reason why there is no statistics from worker. The only thing here - you shoud check if sender is available ([it may not be](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/jpgE9COPcx8))

P.S. I hope you don't do `Await.result` inside some actor - blocking an actor is not recommended at least for your application performance. In some cases it may cause even deadlocks or memory leaks. So await's should be placed somewhere in facade of your system (if underlying framework doesn't support futures).

So it may have a sense to process your answers asynchronously (you will still need to recover them from failure if some actor doesn't respond):

```
 //actor:
 val parent = sender
 for(list <- Future.sequence(qfiltered)) {
     parent ! process(list)
 }

 //in sender (outside of the actors):
 Await(actor ? Get, 10 seconds)
```

Comment: A lot here I didn't know.  Most critically the Await inside an actor.  Trying the latter way but having trouble.  In my actor I have:   for(list <- allInverted) {
        val resp = list.mkString(",")
        println("HERE: "+resp)
        sender ! resp
      }  (sorry, no code editing in comments)  Outside my actor I have:     implicit val t:Timeout = Timeout(15 seconds)
    val answer = Await.result(m ? "stats", 15 seconds)
    println("Answer: "+answer)   So I see my for code outputs the resp very quickly but the response goes to deadletters then finally the Await times out.  Why is that?

Comment: 1) forgot to mention - you should use some permanent link to the parent inside future (see my update) - sender is changing dynamically; 2) it won't help you with timeout problem - so you still need to convert timeouts to the failures as it's described on top of the answer, otherwise the code block inside `for ` will not complete sometimes

Comment: 3) `implicit val timeout` should be less than `Await.timeout` for (2). About SO: you may use "`" for marking code block

Comment: 1*) every `?` generates synthetic actor, which waits for your response, so every time new `sender`. Regarding that future executes asynchronously - there may not be sender at all - so you should capture it before return `val parent = sender ...` as it written in my update.

Comment: :-) That was it.  Beautiful.